# Spot the Differebus

Tags: visual, rebus

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/fortnightly-topic-challenge-26-rebus): [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus).</sup></sup>

---

There are discrepancies between the two images below.  When combined, those differences make a rebus for you to solve.

### Image 1:

[image: image 1]

### Image 2:

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I think I solved it. Based on Sid's excellent finds:

> The differences are a fish's FIN, a bell that goes DING, a DOOR and an E.
> So, FIN+DING+DOOR+E = [***FINDING DORY***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finding_Dory), which the fish clue us in on.
> (There's actually a clownfish right in the middle there.)

Answer (score 10):

Here's what is missing in the 2nd image:

> [image]
>  [image]
>  The "e" in hope
>  There is a "U" missing in the 2nd image on a fish. A very light one indeed.

What are these?

> The 1st one is a bell.
>  The 2nd one is probably a door.

So the final answer:(As found by Walt)

> Finding Dory. (Fin(fish), Ding(Bell), Dor(Door) e (y)

Comment: I cheated with XOR. Here's what's changed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Qnf.png

Comment: Yay. So, Only 3 changes. I was right then...

Comment: @Sid look closer

Comment: Okay, @DavidStarkey You are evil! :P

Comment: DOORBELL is incorrect, by the way.  All missing elements are used in the rebus.